# JS Date "Too many Recursions"

Tags: javascript, datejs

I have a piece of code to validate date ranges that Works in Chrome, but not in IE or Firefox.

I am using Kendo DateTimePicker to get the user dates. For example, if DateTo is an earlier date than DateFrom, DateFrom will be automatically change to the same date as DateTo.

```
if (dateFromEpochTime > dateToEpochTime) {
    date = dateFrom.data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();
    date.setHours(23);
    date.setMinutes(59);
    date.setSeconds(59);

    dateTo.kendoDateTimePicker({
        value: date,
        format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    })
    changedByCode = true;
}
} else {
    if (dateFromEpochTime > dateToEpochTime) {
        date = dateTo.data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();
        date.setHours(00);
        date.setMinutes(00);
        date.setSeconds(00);

        dateFrom.kendoDateTimePicker({
            value: date,
            format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        })
        changedByCode = true;
    }
}
```

This pieces of code that throw the exceptions(Too many recursions for Firefox and Out of stack space for IE) are:

```
dateTo.kendoDateTimePicker({ value: date, format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" })
dateFrom.kendoDateTimePicker({ value: date, format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" })
```

I cant quite figure out what goes wrong there.

P.s: Before the user presses Ok, I can change the dates as many times as I want and my function will correct them. After I press Ok and try to repeat the action things are breaking. Also, I am not including the same JavaScript file twice.

Comment: the exception with "too much recursion" is not generated by the fragment that you posted, it might be retriggered by some change event which tries to updated the content over and over again. The posted code is not sufficient to find the infinite recursion

Comment: Actually, I do have a change event attached to the Date. Do you think that when the date changes dynamically, It enters an infinite loop? I do have a flag that gets set to true if it's changed by code and not the user, and this whole function is not supposed to trigger if the changedByCode variable is true. The weird thing is that it should not work the first time if that is actually the case.

Comment: yes, the problem should be in the way how the event triggers the posted code, if you could provide a fiddle I could find the problem